# Reduce data without loss of information

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose i do have two data tables

```
df1
       x   y    f(x,y)
1      a   A    3
2      b   E    4
3      a   E    5
4      b   A    2
```

and

```
df2
       x   y    f(x,y)
1      a   A    4
2      b   E    4
3      a   E    4
4      b   A    2
```

If we interpret the columns x and y as the influence on some results, than we can say that in the second example (`df2`) the outcome is independent of the column y for x = a. What i would like to do for generating a report is to drop all the columns which don't influence the outcome, hence i would like to create `df2_out` instead of `df2` (in order to avoid some large tables)

```
df2_out
       x   y    f(x,y)
1      a   -    4
2      b   E    4
3      b   A    2
```

whereas `df1` should stay as it is since x,y has an influence on the outcome:

```
df1_out
       x   y    f(x,y)
1      a   A    3
2      b   E    4
3      a   E    5
4      b   A    2
```

How can i achieve this in R? Is there any better way to print the data table?

Comment: So to be clear, if for any given x there are multiple different y but they all produce the same f(x,y), drop those rows? What if vice versa for x and y? Will there be more dependent variable columns? Why is there a blank in the end result and what is the first table for?

Comment: @CalumYou Correct, and the same applies to x (in a more general context, if i have values x1,x2,...,xn and outcomes f(x1,x2,...,xn), then i would like to drop all rows which do not add new informations)

Comment: Appears to be more a statistical "howto" than a coding one. You have not described a specific task. ... yet.

Comment: In your first table, rows 1 and 3 have the same values for `x` and `y` but different values for `f(x,y)`.  Can you clarify how that is happening?  Also, why do you remove the `x` column in row 1 of your output?  That is a column that influences `f(x,y)`, so why take it out?

Comment: @andrew_reece That was a mistake, i updated the first table. Also, the x column should remain in the output for the second table.

Comment: @42- Well, suppose x can take the values a and b and y can take the values A and E. If y=f(a,A)=f(a,E), then i don't want to have two rows [a,A,f(a,A)] and [a,E,f(a,A)]. Instead, i want to have only the row [a,-,y] in the table. That's the task. I think i can do this in R, but i just wanted to know if there is already a short way to do it.

Comment: As long as this is restricted to a simple conditional decision without any implication that this relates to cause and effect then it's almost certainly possible. I use base R functions so am sitting on the sidelines because of the expectation that  a correct solution will involve dplyr functions.

Comment: In your second example, in rows 2 and 3, the outcome is independent of `x`, but this is not represented in your desired output.  Do you only care about cases where the outcome is independent of `y`?  (Also, I added names to your example data, as the output order is reversed from the input order.  Feel free to modify if you don't like it.)

Comment: @andrew_reece It's basically again a mistake. Row 2 and 3 should be summarised too, but thanks a lot for your answer. I think i can go on on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output indicates you are only interested in adjusting cases where the outcome of `f()` is independent of `y`.  You can use `dplyr` methods to do this:

```
library(dplyr)

find_independent <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    inner_join(data %>% 
                 group_by(x, f) %>% 
                 count(), 
               by=c("x", "f")) %>% 
    mutate(y = if_else(n == 2, "_", y)) %>%
    distinct()
}

find_independent(df1)
  x y f
1 a A 3
2 b E 4
3 a E 5
4 b A 2

find_independent(df2)
  x y f
1 a _ 4
2 b E 4
3 b A 2
```

Explanation (using `df2` as an example):

- First, `group_by` `x` and `f` and count the number of occurrences.

  ```
  df2 %>% group_by(x, f) %>% count()
  # A tibble: 3 x 3
  # Groups:   x, f [3]
    x         f     n
    <chr> <int> <int>
  1 a         4     2
  2 b         2     1
  3 b         4     1
  ```
- Merge this count back to the original data frame, and for the rows where `n == 2`, change the value of `y` to `_`.
- Drop duplicate rows (which will be the rows where `y` has no effect on `f`) using `distinct()`.

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), y = c("A", "E", "E", 
"A"), f = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
df2 <- structure(list(x = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), y = c("A", "E", "E", 
"A"), f = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```